# Inefficient SQL query with joined tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 1700 rows of data.  I'm querying it using the query below which pulls complimentary data from related tables too.  It's currently running very slowly (around 10 seconds).

How can I improve the efficiency of this query?

```
SELECT [jobID] ,

  (SELECT orgname
   FROM pm_clients c
   WHERE c.orgID IN
       (SELECT orgid
        FROM pm_jobs j
        WHERE j.jobid=t.jobid
          AND j.jobStatus>=13)) AS orgname ,

  (SELECT sector
   FROM pm_clients c
   WHERE c.orgID IN
       (SELECT orgid
        FROM pm_jobs j
        WHERE j.jobid=t.jobid
          AND j.jobStatus>=13)) AS sector ,

  (SELECT region= CASE country
                      WHEN 1 THEN region
                      ELSE
                             (SELECT countryname
                              FROM AT_A_CountryCodes x
                              WHERE x.id= l.country)
                  END
   FROM PM_ClientDetails l
   WHERE l.userid =
       (SELECT userid
        FROM pm_jobs j
        WHERE j.jobid=t.jobid)) AS region ,

  (SELECT postcode
   FROM PM_ClientDetails l
   WHERE l.userid =
       (SELECT userid
        FROM pm_jobs j
        WHERE j.jobid=t.jobid)) AS postcode ,

  (SELECT firstname
   FROM users u
   WHERE u.userid =
       (SELECT pmid
        FROM pm_jobs j
        WHERE j.jobid=t.jobid)) AS PM ,
       [creationDate] ,

  (SELECT statusName
   FROM pm_jobstatus j
   WHERE j.[statusID]=t.jobStatus) AS JobStatus ,
       [completionDate] ,
       [deadline],
       [jobTitle] ,

  (SELECT currencysymbol
   FROM at_a_currency c
   WHERE c.currencyID =
       (SELECT top(1) quoteCurrency
        FROM PM_Quotes q
        WHERE q.taskid IN
            (SELECT taskid
             FROM pm_tasks x
             WHERE x.jobID=t.jobid))) AS currency ,

  (SELECT sum(quoteSubTotal)
   FROM PM_Quotes q
   WHERE q.taskid IN
       (SELECT taskid
        FROM pm_tasks x
        WHERE x.jobID=t.jobid)) AS subtotal ,

  (SELECT sum(quoteVAT)
   FROM PM_Quotes q
   WHERE q.taskid IN
       (SELECT taskid
        FROM pm_tasks x
        WHERE x.jobID=t.jobid)) AS VAT ,

  (SELECT sum(quoteTotal)
   FROM PM_Quotes q
   WHERE q.taskid IN
       (SELECT taskid
        FROM pm_tasks x
        WHERE x.jobID=t.jobid)) AS total ,

  (SELECT [purchaseOrder]
   FROM pm_jobs j
   WHERE j.jobid=t.jobid) AS purchaseOrder ,

  (SELECT [clientReference]
   FROM pm_jobs j
   WHERE j.jobid=t.jobid) AS clientReference ,

  (SELECT CASE
              WHEN [deadline]='1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1
              WHEN [completiondate]>dateadd(dd,1,[deadline]) THEN 0
              WHEN [completiondate]<=dateadd(dd,1,[deadline])THEN 1
              WHEN [completiondate] IS NULL THEN 0
          END) AS completedOnTime
FROM [PM_jobs] t
WHERE jobStatus>=13
```

### Edit

Thanks to @GuidoG for the response.  Here's the amended query which is much faster now.

```
SELECT j.jobid, 
       c.orgname, 
       c.sector, 
       (SELECT region= CASE country 
                         WHEN 1 THEN region 
                         ELSE (SELECT countryname 
                               FROM   at_a_countrycodes x 
                               WHERE  x.id = l.country) 
                       END)                     AS region, 
       l.postcode, 
       (SELECT firstname 
        FROM   users u 
        WHERE  u.userid = J.pmid)               AS PM, 
       j.creationdate, 
       (SELECT statusname 
        FROM   pm_jobstatus x 
        WHERE  x.[statusid] = j.jobstatus)      AS JobStatus, 
       j.[completiondate], 
       j.[deadline], 
       j.[jobtitle], 
       j.purchaseorder, 
       j.clientreference, 
       (SELECT currencysymbol 
        FROM   at_a_currency c 
        WHERE  c.currencyid = l.clientcurrency) AS currency, 
       Sum(q.quotesubtotal)                     AS subtotal, 
       Sum(q.quotevat)                          AS VAT, 
       Sum(q.quotetotal)                        AS total, 
       (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN j.[deadline] = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 
                 WHEN j.[completiondate] > Dateadd(dd, 1, j.[deadline]) THEN 0 
                 WHEN j.[completiondate] <= Dateadd(dd, 1, j.[deadline])THEN 1 
                 WHEN j.[completiondate] IS NULL THEN 0 
               END)                             AS completedOnTime, 
       Count(t.taskid)                          AS taskcount 
FROM   [pm_jobs] j 
       INNER JOIN pm_clients c 
               ON j.orgid = c.orgid 
       INNER JOIN pm_clientdetails l 
               ON j.userid = l.userid 
       INNER JOIN pm_tasks t 
               ON j.jobid = t.jobid 
       INNER JOIN pm_quotes q 
               ON q.taskid = t.taskid 
                  AND t.jobid = j.jobid 
WHERE  jobstatus >= 13 
GROUP  BY j.jobid, 
          c.orgname, 
          c.sector, 
          l.country, 
          l.region, 
          l.postcode, 
          l.firstname, 
          j.creationdate, 
          j.jobstatus, 
          j.completiondate, 
          j.deadline, 
          j.jobtitle, 
          j.purchaseorder, 
          j.clientreference, 
          l.clientcurrency, 
          J.pmid 
ORDER  BY completiondate DESC
```

Comment: **More correlated subqueries**, I would like to see execution plan of this query

Comment: Please work on the formating, it's really hard to read.

Comment: All those selects can be replaced with CASE and just do a single JOIN with the necessary tables,so you only hit the tables once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider joining instead of subquerying. Here is a small example to get you on your way:

```
SELECT  t.jobID ,
        c.orgName,
        c.sector
FROM [SQL2012_921487_atlas].[dbo].[PM_jobs] t
  inner join pm_clients c on t.orgID = c.orgID
WHERE jobStatus>=13
```

When subquerying like you did, you force SQL Server to read table pm_clients several times; joining enables it to read pm_clients only 1 time.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for your help with this!